# Can I set up an "automatic fix" to a known build bug in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

We are using a package that we know will regularly cause a build error. The solution (until the bug is fixed) is to clean the project and delete the bin and obj folders.

Can I tell Visual Studio 2017 to do this every time it encounters the error and retry the build?

Comment: Can add build action(pre-build) to always clean up bin and obj folders.

Comment: to add to @Kurubaran 's point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx